# Share on Twitter as Card:Summary with deep linking

Tags: android

I need to post a tweet that has text and Url that can be open in my app.
I tried to do it with Web Intent, but it is not scrapping my website for "optimization reasons" as I understood from the Twitter blog. In my website I have the needed meta tags and it is working for the iOS version of the app where the default twitter composer is used. The deep linking works when opening twitter.com from the chrome app and clicking on the Url of the shared tweet. My questions is what should I use so that twitter scraps my website and displays the card with Open in  below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears because the twitter app doesn't want to scrap the link that you give, it may be cause of their link shortening.
I found a workaround solution. You preload the tweet in a webclient inside of your app and load the tweet this way. It will scrap your website and recognize the card. Also found that tweeter removed the whitelisting as a obligation to have the cards.